# IntelliJ editor customisation: javadoc popup to behave like in NetBeans?

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea, javadoc, code-editor

Yesterday I installed IntelliJ IDEA IDE and so far I like it (I used to use NetBeans which I like and Eclipse which I avoid).

When it comes to code editor I would like to change javadoc popup behavior in 2 ways:

1. I set javadoc popup to show after one second (`Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Code completion` -> `Autopopup documentation in`). However it only works when I press `Ctrl + Space` for code completion. When code completion pops up automatically javadoc window does not show. And I want it to. Simply, it is the same issue as the one addressed here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6124
2. The javadoc popup window hides current line (it pops just over code completion window). It would be better if it popped over actual line (with caret) without hiding it.

Is there any plugin that allows such a customisation? Or any setting that I missed?

---

**EDIT 1:**

Here is the picture explaining situation 2:[image]

As you can see because of javadoc popup I cannot see what I am currently writing - part of the word "System."

Comment: For the first question you already have the answer, it's open problem. As for the second one, I can't reproduce it. Please specify your OS and attach a screenshot.

Comment: @CrazyCoder: question updated. System: Windows 7, IDEA 11.1.1 CE. Only happens when javadoc popup cannot pop on the left side of code completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with JavaDoc hiding the code is caused by the low horizontal resolution when the popup cannot fit on the right. Normally displays have enough horizontal pixels to fit it. In any case it's still a bug that can be fixed by displaying the popup above the current line of code.

I've [submitted this bug to YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84828), feel free to vote.

Comment: Yes, it only hides code if it cannot fit on left or right. In which case it should at least pop a little over the code completion popup (gap between them should be longer), so that current line is visible (even if those above it are not).